# Is LDAP used by Active Directory for anything if I only use Kerberos for authentication?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, ldap

In my windows only domain, Kerberos is used for all authentication. The domain controllers I understand replicate & authenticate using RPC. Is LDAP used for anything else? Should I close the unused 389 LDAP port on all Servers and Clients?

Does Active Directory use LDAP used for authorisation, lookup, etc.?

Comment: Do not disable LDAP unless you're using a test environment and you want to see what breaks. LDAP is used for AD resource enumeration, auth, etc. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961766.aspx

Comment: LDAP is used for Service Connection Points (SCP) in the Config partition, so likely yes, LDAP is used

Comment: I presume you want file ownership & permissions to map to usernames and or group names?

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not.  LDAP is fundamental to many processes in Active Directory.  For example:

- When you perform an interactive logon on a client, the client performs a series of DNS lookups to determine the best domain controller, then performs a series of tests on tcp/389.
- The Active Directory schema is downloaded to the client using LDAP on tcp/389.
- The Group Policy Client uses LDAP to retrieve the policy information component which is stored in Active Directory.
- Many of the command line tools and system-integrated management tools use LDAP (Active Directory Users and Computers, Active Directory Sites and Services, etc).
- A TON of other stuff.

It's fairly easy to perform a network packet capture to confirm this.

It sounds like you may be confusing NTLM with Kerberos.  It may be possible to use Kerberos in place of NTLM/2, although the client will attempt to fall back to NTLM/2 if Kerberos authentication is not possible.

Additionally, it is not possible to use only LDAPS tcp/636 in place of tcp/389 if you have certificates installed on your domain controllers.  This would not provide any useful benefit, as LDAPS is primarily intended for applications that authenticate using a simple bind (username+password).

Comment: There are two additional notes to otherwise wonderful answer:

- LDAP tcp/389 is used normally within Active Directory for simple binds by enforcing STARTTLS extension; it also is used with GSSAPI binds.

- LDAP udp/389 is known as **Connectionless LDAP** and is used by AD clients to discover domain controllers and certain capabilities of those servers.

Comment: @greg-askew  1. Isn't RPC used for all this as well?
2. So Kerberos is used for authentication and LDAP for authorisation?

Comment: @Reemus, see my comment to the other answer.

Comment: @Remus: apparently not.